# Find not possible combinations of rows & columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Based on SQL Server, I have multiple rows with multiple columns. Each row contains a product-configuration which is different in at least one column. Now I need to know which are the not existing configurations. The three columns are only an example to make it easier to understand.

An example of data:

| Product | Size | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shirt | S | Red |
| Shirt | S | Blue |
| Shirt | S | Black |
| Shirt | M | Red |
| Shirt | M | Blue |
| Shirt | L | Yellow |

As a result, those configurations are missing:

| Product | Size | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shirt | S | Yellow |
| Shirt | M | Black |
| Shirt | M | Yellow |
| Shirt | L | Red |
| Shirt | L | Blue |
| Shirt | L | Black |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon's answer doesn't take into account nullable columns, here is one that does:

```
select p.product, s.size, c.color
from (select distinct product from t) p cross join
     (select distinct size from t) s cross join
     (select distinct color from t) c
except
select t.product, t.size, t.color
from t;
```

If you have actual `product`, `size` and `color` tables, it will be more performant to use those instead of `select distinct... from t`

Comment: FWIW: the answer from Gordon Linoff is standard SQL that is widely supported. `EXCEPT` is not supported by all DMBS.

Comment: Also i would assume `product` can not be NULL, so it really doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Kaii I don't believe that is true see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060151/ansi-sql-standard-for-oracle-minus-keyword

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross join` to generate all the rows.  Then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select p.product, s.size, c.color
from (select distinct product from t) p cross join
     (select distinct size from t) s cross join
     (select distinct color from t) c left join
     t
     on p.product = t.product and
        s.size = t.size and
        c.color = t.color
where t.product is null;
```